# Insert n characters in the nth row using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

> Given a number `n` and a character `c`, the task is to replace the innerHTML of an element with `n` rows of text. The first row should have one copy of `c`, the second row should have two copies of `c`, etc. `<br>` tags are to be inserted to separate each row.

I've been thinking that a nested `for` loop might be appropriate here, where the outer `for` creates the rows, and the inner `for` repeats the characters in each row, but just can't put it together in my mind, and not sure if that's even a good approach.

I am thinking something perhaps like:

```
for(i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for(j = 1, j <= n; j++) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = c;
  }
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += <br>;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "n" rows of text? How are the rows made using some other elements like a "p" or "h1"?

Comment: @SaumilSoni Hi, suppose you have a JavaScript variable n that captures a number inputted by the user. And you have a JS variable c that captures a character inputted by the user. Then you have to insert n rows of c into an HTML element (e.g., a div), where the nth row has exactly n characters, c.

Comment: @SaumilSoni The OP simply wants a pyramid.

Comment: Have you tried to do something? StackOverflow is not the place where people solve your tasks for you. If you tried to do it and stumbled upon a problem, we could help you.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I'll edit my post to include a rough idea what I've been thinking.

Comment: You don't need nested loops to do this.  A single loop is sufficient:  http://jsfiddle.net/qjvc0ppq/

Comment: @aroth It does work, but why are you doing `window.fillElement = function(letter, numRows, elem)` instead of `function fillElement(letter, numRows, elem)`? It may definitely confuse the beginner. Please, check this out: jsfiddle.net/ykurmangaliyev/qjvc0ppq/1

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev Yes, it looks like he's adding the function to the gloabl window object. Isn't that considered bad practice?

Comment: @yroc In JavaScript, in the global context it is the same as `var fillElement = function()`, because `window` is a default context :)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev - Careful with that second comment there, lest you introduce some confusion of your own.  What you say is correct in vanilla JavaScript, but _not_ on jsFiddle with default settings (because it implicitly wraps all of the code in an `onLoad` handler by default)...and where'd my previous reply go?  No matter; I used `window` to make the function explicitly global, because otherwise it wouldn't be due to how jsFiddle's default settings work.  It's just a habit I have when writing any code on jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested `for` loops typically have bad performance implications, but assuming you're doing this on a small scale, this should give you an idea of what to go for http://jsfiddle.net/mrodkc1u/1/

However, since the number of rows will be the same number of characters in the largest row, you shouldn't need to use a nested loop. Here's an updated fiddle with just one loop http://jsfiddle.net/mrodkc1u/2/